# Jquery plugin not working

Tags: php, jquery

I am very new to jQuery. I am trying to use a plugin called Searchable Dropdown, that I got from here: http://jsearchdropdown.sourceforge.net/
. but I cannot figure out how to make it work.. What am I doing wrong?

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.searchabledropdown-1.0.8.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("select").searchable();
    });
</script>

</head>

<?php
echo "<form method='post' action='' id='employeesselection'>
  <select    name='select_employee' id='select_employee'>";
       while($row=mysql_fetch_array($employees)){
            $selected = ($row['Id'] == $_POST['select_employee'])?'selected="selected"':'';
    echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$row['Id'].'">'.$row['Etunimi'].' - '. $row['Sukunimi'].'</option>';

}
   echo "</select></form>";
```

The select is working fine but searching in the select as the jQuery should enable, is not working.

Comment: Check your console for errors.

Comment: I don't know how Searchable Dropdown works, but marking `//irrelevant` on the `<option>`s of your dropdown seems incredibly naive.

Isn't that the content that's to be searched?

Comment: @rockerest I just thought it is not important.. I updated my code.

Comment: Use http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ it works great for me =)

Comment: Is `scripts/jquery.searchabledropdown-1.0.8.min.js` getting loaded correctly? File path correct, file exists, etc.

Comment: @AxelA.Grazx Chosen rip off :)

Comment: @AxelA.Grazx What's your point by suggesting a different library? I don't think it's a library problem

Comment: Post a reduction that we can run... http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I think I will just use Axel's plugin, because it seemed to work. :)

Comment: @JuanMendes how can jsfiddle run my code that has database retrievals?

Comment: Shouldn't `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js` be `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js`? At least I've never tried it with `//`.

Comment: No, // is a protocol relative URL. It will attempt to load https on https servers and http on http servers: http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Answer (score 0):

Try also to give your code some semantic:

```
<?php 

// DATABASE CONNECTION
// DATABASE QUERY

 ?>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<!-- CSS -->

</head>

<body>
    <form action="" method="post" id="employeesselection">
        <select name="select_employee" id="select_employee">
            <?php while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $employees ) ) {
                $selected = ( $row['id'] == $_POST['select_employee'] ) ? ' selected ' : '';
            ?>      
                <option <?php echo $selected ?> value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
                    <?php echo $row['etunimi'] ?> - <?php echo $row['sukunimi'] ?>
                </option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </form>

<!-- All Javascript down here -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.searchabledropdown-1.0.8.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("select").searchable();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe the error isn't in your javascript but in php...

Good luck debugging!

Answer (score 0):

I belive its to do with Jquery 1.9.1.

Replace

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

With

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```